# Let $I= (X_1,X_2) \cap (X_3,X_4)$. Is $ara(I)≥3$? Is $ara(I)≥4$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, local-cohomology

This question is related to
[Can $(X_1,X_2) \cap (X_3,X_4)$ be generated with two elements from $k[X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702095/can-x-1-x-2-cap-x-3-x-4-be-generated-with-two-elements-from-kx-1-x-2-x)

> Let $R=k[X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4]$ and $I= (X_1,X_2) \cap (X_3,X_4)$. I know that $4≥\operatorname{ara}(I)≥\operatorname{ht} I=2$. Is $\operatorname{ara}(I)≥3$? Is $\operatorname{ara}(I)≥4$? (Here $\operatorname{ara}$ means *arithmetic rank*, that is, the least number of elements of $R$ required to generate an ideal which has the same radical as $I$.)

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Are you following any book or lecture note on local cohomology? I would try to use Meyer-Vietories sequence.

Comment: i read 6 chapter of "Local Cohomology-An Algebraic Introduction with Geometric Applications-By M. P. Brodmann -online publish 2010"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ideal is well-known to have arithmetic rank $3$, and is not a set-theoretic complete intersection.

To see that $\text{ara}(I) \le 3$, notice that $I = (X_1X_3, X_1X_4, X_2X_3, X_2X_4) = \sqrt{(X_1X_3, X_2X_4, X_1X_4 + X_2X_3)}$, since $(X_1X_4)^2 = X_1X_4(X_1X_4 + X_2X_3) - (X_1X_3)(X_2X_4)$ (and similarly for $(X_2X_3)^2$).

To see that $\text{ara}(I) \ge 3$, note that $H^i_I(R) = 0$ for $i > \text{ara}(I)$, where $H^i_I(\_)$ is the $i^\text{th}$ local cohomology with support in $I$. It thus suffices to show $H^3_I(R) \ne 0$, which can be done by Mayer-Vietoris. If $p = (X_1, X_2)$, $q = (X_3, X_4)$, then $I = p \cap q$, and $p + q = m = (X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4)$. Now $H^4_p(R) = H^4_q(R) = 0$ (since $p, q$ are complete intersections) and $H^4_m(R) \ne 0$ (since $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay). By Mayer-Vietoris, there is an exact sequence

$$H^3_I(R) \to H^4_m(R) \to H^4_p(R) \oplus H^4_q(R) = 0$$

so $H^3_I(R)$ surjects onto a nonzero module, hence is nonzero.

Comment: @ucf: It suffices to check that the (images of the) $4$ given generators are linearly independent in the $k$-vector space $I \otimes_R R/m \cong I/mI$. This approach was explained in [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/702271/115654) to your linked question, and another approach was also given by user26857. Please consider accepting one of the answers there, or clarifying your confusion more