# Ideal Generated by Three Elements in Polynomial Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> How would one prove that the ideal $(xy,xz,yz)$ of $k[x,y,z]$ for some field $k$, cannot be generated by two polynomials. In other words, prove:
>   $$(xy,xz,yz) \neq (f,g)\; \forall f,g \in k[x,y,z].$$

Furthermore, can somebody abstract this fact and prove it for $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$? Maybe that the ideal of certain combinations of multiplied variables $x_i$ is not generated by less elements. Please ask if my question is unclear.

Edit: Specifically, I want to say that the ideal generated by all combinatorial products of $n-1$ variables in $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ cannot be generated by less elements. But if somebody has a different abstraction, please share.

Comment: Concerning to the edit: This also follows immediately if use the method of my answer. Then $I$ is homogeneous generated by homogeneous elements of degree $n-1$, while $mI$ is homogeneous generated by homogeneous elements of degree $n$. (Here $m=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.)

Answer (score 5):

As I have already explained in the comments under [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/702271/121097), if $I=(xy,xz,yz)$ then it's enough to check the dimension of the $k$-vector space $I/mI$, where $m=(x,y,z)$. It is not hard to show that the (residue classes of) $xy, yz,zx$ are linearly independent over $k$: if $axy+byz+czx\in mI$ with $a,b,c\in k$, then $a=b=c=0$ because $mI$ is a homogeneous ideal generated by homogeneous elements of degree $3$, while $axy+byz+czx$ would have degree $2$ if one of the elements $a,b,c$ is non-zero. Conclusion: $\dim_kI/mI=3$, so the minimal number of generators of $I$ is $3$.

**Edit.** One can also think like this: $I$ is generated by homogeneous polynomials of degree $2$. If $I_2$ is the set of homogeneous polynomials of degree $2$ in $I$, then $I_2$ is the  $k$-vector space $kxy\oplus kyz\oplus kzx$. On the other hand, if $I=(f,g)$, then the homogeneous components of $f$ and $g$ are of degree at least $2$ (because $f,g\in I$), so $I_2=kf_2+kg_2$. (Here $f_2$ and $g_2$ denote the homogeneous components of degree $2$ of $f$ and $g$.) This is clearly a contradiction.

Comment: How exactly is the k-vector space you described related to the minimal number of generators of an ideal I. Does this always work if k is a field? Sorry my abstract algebra is not very advanced.

Comment: @MatthewLevy In that comments (see comment #3) I've explained very clear that $\dim_kI/mI$ equals the minimal number of generators of $I$. (This actually holds for finitely generated graded modules, not only for graded ideals.)

Comment: It certainly seems reasonable, is there a more straightforward proof, at least for the simpler case of k[x,y,z]. Your way seems like it would solve the abstract problem as well, but I don't think I have the mathematical knowledge to follow it.

Answer (score 3):

This is the most straightforward version of the canonical proof (i.e. what user26857 posted) that I can think of.  I have run into problems, more than once, explaining this proof to skeptics, so hopefully this adds some clarity, rather than more confusion.

---

Let $R=k[x,y,z]$.

If $R_{\geq 2}$ is the ideal of all polynomials with lowest degree $\geq 2$, and $R_2$ is the $k$ vector space of all homogeneous polynomials with degree exactly $2$, then we can define a $k$-linear map $\pi: R_{\geq 2}\to R_2$ by *throwing out the terms of degree $\geq 3$*, e.g. $\pi(x^2 + xz + y^3) = x^2 + xz$.  It is not hard to see that this map is $k$-linear—it is merely a standard projection.

There is only one property of this projection that we really need: If $f\in R_{\geq 2}$, and $g\in R$ has constant term $g_0$, then $\pi(gf) = g_0 \pi(f)$.

(Proof: $(g-g_0)f$ has only terms of degree $\geq 3$, so $\pi((g-g_0)f) = 0$.  Therefore $\pi(cf + (g-g_0)f) = \pi(g_0f) + \pi((g-g_0)f) = g_0\pi(f)$.)

It follows immediately that if $I\subset R_{\geq 2}$ is an ideal, and $I$ is generated by $f_1,\cdots,f_n$, then $\pi(I)$ is generated by $\pi(f_1),\cdots,\pi(f_n)$ as a $k$-vector space.  Explicitly: $\pi(Rf_1 + \cdots + Rf_n) = k f_1 + \cdots + k f_n$.

In the particular case $I=(xy,xz,yz)$, we can easily see that $\pi(I)$, the homogeneous degree $2$ part of $I$, has dimension $3$ over $k$.  By the above, this means that $I$ cannot possibly be generated by $2$ elements, as they would map, under $\pi$, to a generating set that is too small.

---

In other words, this property that the minimal number of generators of an ideal $I$, generated by homogeneous polynomials of the same degree, equals $\dim_{R/\mathfrak{m}} I/\mathfrak{m} I = \dim_k I/\mathfrak{m} I$, where $\mathfrak{m} = (x,y,z)$, is an immediate and trivial statement once you are comfortable with this operation of *throwing out higher-order terms*.  And the above generalizes easily.

Comment: @user26857 It seems tricky to find a crystal-clear way of saying all this.  Once, I had someone—a graduate student—express doubt that this $\pi$ was even a linear map, so intuition seems to play a heavy role in whether one thinks these are easy or difficult facts.

Comment: See the linked answer in my comment to the post - in particular, it's not necessary to worry about the map $\pi$ (or its linearity) at all

Comment: @zcn I agree that that's the right way to think about it, but somehow this requires enough intuition about modules to be comfortable with the assertion that $A/\mathfrak{m}$ acts on $I/\mathfrak{m}I$.  Yes, this fact should be "elementary", but as Matthew's comments illustrate, this approach can come across as "advanced", or not "straightforward".

Answer (score 0):

If $(xy,xz,yz)=(f,g) for some f,g∈k[x,y,z]$, $xy \in (xy,yz,xz) \Rightarrow either f=x+c$ or $g=x+c$ or $f=xy+c$ or $g=xy+c $.[the first two cases will be contradicted easily (check!!)].  WLOG let $f=xy+c$ Now take  $yz \in (xy,yz,xz)\Rightarrow g=z$ or $y$ or $yz$ (note if $c=yz$ & $g=xy$ then we will run our arguement with g in stead of f) [here also the first two cases will be contradicted easily], Now consider $xz \in (xy,yz,xz)$ but $xz \notin (xy,yz)$.
Contradiction.

Now extend this idea to n variable.

Comment: $xy \in (xy,yz,xz) \Rightarrow either f=x$ or $g=x$ or $f=xy$ or $g=xy $. Really?

Comment: If $(xy,xz,yz)=(f,g) for some f,g∈k[x,y,z]$

Comment: Please show me how to prove this.

Comment: Tell me if $xy\in (f,g)$ what will be the possibilities?

Comment: $f=xy-XXL$ and $g=XXL$.

Comment: Yeah then I have to edit that this $XXL$ must be of the form $xy$ or $yz$ or $zx$ or $x$ or $y$ or $z$.

Comment: And contradiction arises in these cases also.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if from $xy\in(f,g)$ you can draw any conclusion about the form of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: This method may be cumbersome but for x,y,z this can be carried out.